# Print a WebView content on duplex (front and back) printer with different margins for front and back

Tags: ios, airprint, uiprintpagerenderer

I have a WebView, and want to print it's HTML content via AirPrint. I want to add custom page margins to this content. I was able to achieve it using my own subclass of `UIPrintPageRenderer`

Now, whenever my app user is using duplex printer (printing front and back of the page), I want to set different page margins for front page and back page.

UIPrintPageRenderer was not able to achieve this task, since it asks for `headerHeight`, `footerHeight` as a single property and it does not have something like `headerHeight(forPage:)`

I also explored option of creating PDF file, but apparently PDF files are generated using UIPrintPageRenderer only.

Also, I don't know how to override or get custom `UIViewPrintFormatter` from WKWebView, since this object is returned by WebView's function `func viewPrintFormatter() -> UIViewPrintFormatter`